# PowerShell: Azure AD Module, Bulk Enable O365 command Error

Tags: powershell, azure, office365

First post here.. I have a small issue with a PowerShell command. I'm using the Azure AD module and trying to bulk enable users for O365 using a CSV file and this guide: http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/04/23/provisioning-and-licensing-office-365-accounts-with-powershell/

I've gotten all the way through without issues and can enable a single user using the method outlined in that article, but when trying to bulk enable I get the following:

Command:

```
Import-CSV -Path sapusers_sample.csv | ForEach-Object {Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -AddLicenses wcs1:STANDARDWOFFPACK -LicenseOptions $options}
```

Error:

```
Set-MsolUserLicense : You must provide a required property: Parameter name: UsageLocation
```

(`$options` is just a variable containing the disabled plans, we don't want users to have Exchange enabled just yet)

The weird thing is, when reading the help text for `Set-MsolUserLicense`, there is no `UsageLocation` parameter listed. And when I try to add it, for instance `Set-MsolUserLicense -UsageLocation US`, PS returns the following:

```
Set-MsolUserLicense : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'UsageLocation'
```

So... is PS asking for a parameter for `Set-MsolUserLicense` that doesn't exist?.. or am I misinterpreting this.. any help is appreciated - thanks!!!!

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office 365 requires the user's usage location to determine which service are available to them. Thus, `UsageLocation` is a property of a user, which can be set with the `-UsageLocation` parameter of `Set-MsolUser` or `New-MsolUser`:

```
 Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName bob@contoso.com -UsageLocation "US";
```

Once you've set the user's `UserLocation`, you should be able to assign licenses to that user.

If the usage location is the same for all your users, you can include it directly in you `ForEach-Object` loop:

```
Import-CSV -Path sapusers_sample.csv | ForEach-Object {
    Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName `
        -UsageLocation "US";
    Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName `
        -AddLicenses wcs1:STANDARDWOFFPACK `
        -LicenseOptions $options;
}
```

You could also just as easily add a "UsageLocation" column to the input CSV:

```
Import-CSV -Path sapusers_sample.csv | ForEach-Object {
    Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName `
        -UsageLocation $_.UsageLocation;
    Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName `
        -AddLicenses wcs1:STANDARDWOFFPACK `
        -LicenseOptions $options;
}
```